# parsing a log file with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am try to parse a log file with the following code:

```
    if [[ $line -match "=====.*" ]]; then
        awk $2 = $vFiler;
        echo "$vFiler";
```

Explanation:

there are lines starting with a pattern like `=====` or 'vol/...' followed by a name
I want find all lines who start with `=====` or'vol/...' and set the string that follows equals a variable, but I am really struggling doing it, i thought about a if command with awk (I know that -match is no real command).

Input looks like this:

```
===== vfiler0
/vol/vol0   

===== vFiler1
/vol/vol1
```

output should be:

```
vFiler, Type
vFiler0, /vol/vol0
vFiler1, /vol/vol1
```

can you guys help me? I am trying to do this in a bash script
is it possible to get it a "if ..." like i tried above?

Comment: Provide some examples of input and expected output.

Comment: Do you even know how awk works ? What language is this supposed to be written in ?

Comment: ===== vfiler0
/vol/vol0

===== vFiler1

Comment: Edit your question to better describe what you are trying to do and include the input/output there.

Comment: the file i want to read looks like that piece i posted above, I want to get the strings vFiler0 and vFiler1

Comment: You have suggested at the bottom of your question that your true requirements may be more complex. Perhaps you should edit your question to explain what they are, as the best advice may vary depending on the specific details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the following:

```
awk -v RS="=====" -v OFS="," 'BEGIN {print "vFiler", "Type" } NF{print $1, $2}' file
```

It returns:

```
vFiler,Type
vfiler0,/vol/vol0
vFiler1,/vol/vol1
```

What we do is to set the record separator as `=====`. This way, a block of `====` will be handled every time. Then, we print the first and second field whenever there is at least one (`NF`).

Comment: great thanks, did not think it would work with a single awk command

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/=====/{print $2}' inputFile
```

will give output as

```
vfiler0
vFiler1
```

Comment: is it possible to do it with a if[...]? since I want to check for more things than just the =====

Comment: @howdoesthiswork: yep, it would be possible to check for more things in awk - if you are curious how, see how awk actually works: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring13/cos333/awk.help

Answer (score 0):

does this help?

```
grep -Po '^={5}\s+\K.*' file
```

Comment: sorry that i didnt wrote it in my question ... but is it possible to do it with a if[...]? since I want to check for more things than just the =====

Comment: @howdoesthiswork first thing, write complete requirement in question.