# shell script to parse a huge log file

Tags: shell, parsing, awk

I want to parse a really huge log file, here a example shortcut:

```
===== fspCIV0
/vol/vol0 -sec=sys,rw=fspsanp42.net,root=fspsanp42.net,nosuid
===== fcvCIS01
/vol/ARDW -sec=sys,rw
/vol/ARDW -sec=sys,rw
/vol/ARDW -sec=sys,rw,nosuid
/vol/ARDW -sec=sys,rw
/vol/ARDW -sec=sys,rw=none
/vol/lonulixda -sec=sys,rw=fcvsan10.net:fcvsan11.net,root=fcvsan10.net:fcvsan11.net
```

it continues that way for a few more pages...

The desired output should be:

```
vFiler, Type, host
fspCIV0, /vol/vol0, fspsanp42.net
fcvCIS01, /vol/lonulixda, fcvsan10.net
fcvCIS01, /vol/lonulixda, fcvsan11.net
```

The vFiler line always starts with a '=====' followed by a string
after this every other line starts with '/vol/...' which is meant to be the Type, so far I already managed to get the information, but the real problem starts with the server names who are listed after 'rw= or ro=' (and repeated after 'root=').

It should ignore every line where there are no servers listed after rw= or ro=.

For every new server even with the same Type, I want to start a new line, if there is more than one server listed they are seperated by a ':' .

I thought that it would be possible to list it with a loop that contains IFS ':' . 
But im not quite sure how to write it...

can someone help me? thanks in advance

I have tried it with:

```
awk -v RS="=====" -v OFS="," 'BEGIN {print "vFiler", "Type" } NF{print $1, $2}'
```

and a while loop I think that might be working:

```
while IFS=':' read -r host $1-$#;
```

but I dont know if the loop is correct or where to put it.

Comment: This should have been your first question, instead of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26587589/2088135)

Comment: In the previous question you got some results. Have you tried "playing" with them?

Comment: yeah i already had a loop with IFS before i asked the first question and wanted to try it myself but its not working

Comment: @howdoesthiswork then show us what you have tried. *its not working* is ambiguous

Comment: yep I added what I was trying around

Comment: @howdoesthiswork : try script given below, and get back with the result if you need any changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script might help you

**Input**

```
akshay@Aix:/tmp$ cat file
===== fspCIV0
/vol/vol0 -sec=sys,rw=fspsanp42.net,root=fspsanp42.net,nosuid
===== fcvCIS01
/vol/ARDW -sec=sys,rw
/vol/ARDW -sec=sys,rw
/vol/ARDW -sec=sys,rw,nosuid
/vol/ARDW -sec=sys,rw
/vol/ARDW -sec=sys,rw=none
/vol/lonulixda -sec=sys,rw=fcvsan10.net:fcvsan11.net,root=fcvsan10.net:fcvsan11.net
```

**Script**

```
akshay@Aix:/tmp$ cat parse_log.awk
BEGIN{
    print "vFiler", "Type", "host"
}
/=====/{
    vFiler=$2
    next
}
match($0,/root=[^,]*/){
    n=split(substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5),N,/:/)
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)print vFiler,$1,N[i];
}
```

**How to execute ?**

```
akshay@Aix:/tmp$ awk -vOFS="," -f parse_log.awk file
```

**Output**

```
vFiler,Type,host
fspCIV0,/vol/vol0,fspsanp42.net
fcvCIS01,/vol/lonulixda,fcvsan10.net
fcvCIS01,/vol/lonulixda,fcvsan11.net
```

Comment: This looks good, but now a really dumb question ... I want to test it on the the long log file, what command do I have to write in the script so it runs on the log file when I execute it

Comment: @howdoesthiswork type on terminal like this :- `awk -vOFS="," -f parse_log.awk your_log_file`

Comment: Okay, now it works but it does only list the hosts of the first Type in every vFiler, it ignores the case where there is another Type with hosts on the same vFiler

Comment: @howdoesthiswork : okay I just edited my post please use updated script

Comment: Note, GNU awk (i.e. `gawk`) required for the `match` function.

Comment: just one more question, what kind of script language is this?

Comment: @howdoesthiswork : This is awk script, type `man awk` on terminal, also you can read more about this here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK

Answer (score 0):

simple version would be

```
awk  -F[,\ =] '/^=====/{filler=$7} /r[wo]=[^.]*.net/{split($5, a, ":"); for (i in a) print filler,$1,a[i]}'
```

which would give output as

```
fspCIV0 /vol/vol0 fspsanp42.net
fcvCIS01 /vol/lonulixda fcvsan10.net
fcvCIS01 /vol/lonulixda fcvsan11.net
```

Comment: I do not get any output when I execute this command on my file

Comment: it should work if i put the path of my log file behind the command shouldnt it?

Comment: so, awk -F[,\ =] '/^=====/{filler=$7} /r[wo]=[^.]*.net/{split($5, a, ":"); for (i in a) print filler,$1,a[i]}' inputFile - is not enough?

Comment: /home/pmoberma/test/exports_n7760.out

Comment: I did it with the exact same way, but its not working I have no idea why

Comment: there is just nothing happening

Comment: yes, but much longer, I just tried it with the content as above but there is still nothing happening

Comment: oh no its not exactly the same ... I just realized that this were just some random letters, its works fine when I copy the example from above but not for the real log file which only looks the same in the structure

Comment: so basically everything has different names but the structure is the same

Comment: vFiler, Type (always start with /vol/) and host (every host has .net at the end) have different names, the rest is the same

Comment: the input file is .txt

Comment: pattern is the same, but sometimes there are more than 1 hosts listed in one Type

Comment: which is what you want as per the question i guess. Also would you please remove sum comments from this post so that it wont look clusterd thank you :)

Comment: exactly, thats what i want